# How to add key press Event manually using jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, key

Here I'm having two text boxes which suggests country names using `jquery`

```
<input type="text" size="50" id="suggestBox"/>

<input type="text" size="50" id="suggestBox1"/>
```

**Now, if I select any value from text `box-1`  then second text `box-2` should automatically suggest values**

**For that, I have used code below:**

```
function callback()
{
    document.getElementById('suggestBox1').focus();
    document.getElementById('suggestBox1').value=' ';

$('#suggestBox').change(function(){
        $('#suggestBox1').focus().trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 17 });
    });
}

jQuery(function() {
    $('input#suggestBox').jsonSuggest(testData.countryCodes, {onSelect:callback});
    $('input#suggestBox1').jsonSuggest(testData.countryCodes);
});
```

But it does not show any result, does anyone have an idea as to why?

Thanks

Comment: `$('#suggestBox1').change(function(){` shouldnt this be `$('#suggestBox').change(function(){` as per your requirement

Comment: i have used $('#suggestBox') then also it is not coming?

Comment: Can u Simulate the same on jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PgAKc/1/

Comment: but there it is not working

Comment: http://udoo.in/JSON/demo.html  you can check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
event = jQuery.Event("keypress");
event.which = 17; 
$("input").trigger(event );
$('#suggestBox1').focus().trigger(event);
```

Comment: thanks for giving your valuable answer, but it is also not woking.